# Error: Unicode char \u8 when importing bibliography

Tags: bibtex, citing, input-encodings, jabref

I have a LaTeX document in which I improt .bib database

```
\bibliography{LagrangianRelax}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

I am getting an error (I know its quite common): `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�d� not set up for use with LaTeX.` when making a citation.

I dont know why - my editor is set to UTF8, JabRef (in which I create the .bib database) is set to UTF and I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks for any tips...

Comment: Unicode contains more than 60.000 chars and latex does not load a suitable definition for all of them. It only predefines a small subset. You can add more definitions e.g. with the newunicodechar package.

Comment: @Smajl You could try to use Heiko Oberdiek's `inputenx` package instead of `inputenc`, because it covers more unicode slots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the reason is that you compile with `bibtex`, not `biber`.  Bibtex  doesn't understand utf8 — not even 8-bit encoding. Probably you should use `biblatex`
 — in which case the syntax for loading the database and a bibliography style should be (for the alphabetic style, for instance):

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}    
\addbibresource{LagrangianRelax.bib}
```

I'm unsure whether it's *exactly*   the same style as the `alphabetic.bst` style file, but biblatex styles are much easier to customise than .bst files.

Comment: Your MWE is set to generate authoryear-style citations. Is there a biblatex style that approximates the `alpha` style more closely?

Comment: @Mico: I don't know the details of the `alpha` bibstyle — except of course it sorts alphabetically. I once tried to have such details for classic .bst files, but didn't succeed in finding a documentation.

Comment: The `alpha` bibliography style generally creates citation labels of the form `Jon90` and `GKP94` for items published by Jones in 1990 and Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik in 1994, respectively. In addition, as you've noted, entries are sorted alphabetically (by authors' names).

Comment: @Mico: it then suffices to load biblatex with the `citestyle=alphabetic` option. The different citation styles are explained in § 3.3.1 of the doc.

Comment: I guess I'm unsure why, given that the OP has stated that he/she uses the `alpha` bibliography style under bibtex, you would write `style=authoryear` in the solution.

Comment: @Mico: Looking deeper in biblatex  documentation, I finally found there's  an `alphabetic` style for references as well as for citations. I've modified my answer.